# writing huffman encoding back to a file

Tags: c++

I am writing a huffman encoding program to compress a text file. I converted the text file to its huffman encoded value, and I need to write it to a file.The problem is i cant recognise the the texts that get written back to the file.

note:I have the huffman tree.My text editor cant recognise the encoding that gets written back

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't recognise"?  What are you expecting the result to look like, and what do you actually get?

Comment: If there's not a "?" in your post, it's not a question.

Comment: Congratulations, it is working ;)

Comment: I'm not sure about your rule on "If there is not a ?, then it is not a question", it could be easily circumnavigated. Do you agree?

Comment: ...waiting for the next edit to be a replacement of the last '.' with a '?'.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing the compressed data , you'll need to write out the huffman tree also. When uncompressing, first tree has to be read back  and reconstructed, and then text to be uncompressed by traversing the tree. 
  For small files, the compressed file can be actually bigger .. because of this tree.

huffman will .. probably give a very poor compression.

Comment: I have a compressed data .I am just writting back the compressed data to a file using bits to ensure that i dont wast memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your problem stems from not knowing the Huffman table/tree used to compress the data. Huffman comes in three basic varieties: dynamic, static, and two-pass.

In static Huffman, all compression is always done with the same table. In this case, the decompressor is preloaded with a copy of the same table as the compressor (always) uses.

In dynamic Huffman, you build the Huffman table/tree based on the contents of the input. The decompressor builds a similar table in sync with the compressor, based on the contents of the compressed file.

In two-pass Huffman, you first scan over the data to figure out the character frequencies (and therefore, and optimal compression tree). In this case, you have to transmit the Huffman tree (or frequencies to build a tree) with the data for the decompressor to reconstruct the data.